# Operation Id is changeable when trace WPF operations by embedded ETW provider

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, dispatcher, etw

I'm trying to trace WPF operations by ETW provider embedded into PresentationSource.
When I traced real application I was bit by changing already triggered operation Id from Post to Start phase.

At the source code I found that Id is relied on address of the object which might be changed during GC operation:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherOperation.cs,dff34e59b0cffd1e

Does anybody know how to track by ETW such object relocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such movement might be tracked by:

ProviderName: "Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime"
EventName: "GC/GCBulkMovedObjectRanges"
Event might be parsed by ClrTraceEventParser.GCBulkMovedObjectRanges

Originally answered there:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b6f9918-60ee-4e23-b443-42b4895775ad/how-to-track-change-of-wpf-dispatcheroperation-id?forum=netfxbcl

***UPDATE:***

Due to tracing WPF operations I would say that approach with changeable ID is worst ever implementation. It is implemented incorrectly.

Id has fixed address position during gather that Id but whole operation isn't ensure that tracing message contains correct address. It might be already moved when event is raised.

I got next event sequence:
- WClientUIContextPost
- GCBulkMovedObjectRanges
- WClientUIContextPost

Where last one may contains moved or unmoved Id. Only gods know.

The event GCBulkMovedObjectRanges is usable in 95%. But sometimes it is fails.

So it no way to track it reliable. Very sadly that this architectural/implementation mistake turn feature unusable.